# Why am I getting a value back from Long.parseUnsignedLong when I shouldn't be

Tags: java, long-integer, primitive-types

When I do

```
Long.parseUnsignedLong("FBD626CC4961A4FC", 16)
```

I get back `-300009666327239428`

Which seems wrong, since the meaning of unsigned long according to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2550367/1754020 is that the range is always positive.

To get the correct number from this HEX value I do

```
BigInteger value = new BigInteger("FBD626CC4961A4FC", 16);
```

When I print value it prints the correct value. but if I do `value.longValue()`

again I get the same `-300009666327239428` is this of the number being too big and overflowing ?

Comment: Print `Long.MAX_VALUE` and compare. Yes, it's too big to fit in a `long`.

Comment: so it doesn't throw an exception ?

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseUnsignedLong-java.lang.String-int-) claims that it should throw a `NumberFormatException` if "The value represented by the string is larger than the largest unsigned long, 2^64-1."

I'm sorry I don't have an answer though.

Comment: @tsm And `Long.MAX_VALUE` is lower than this. Two times lower since a `long` is signed.

Comment: `long` is always signed even if you parse or convert it as if it was unsigned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java 8 does (somewhat) support **unsigned longs**, however, you can't just print them directly. Doing so will give you the result that you saw.

If you have an unsigned long

```
Long number = Long.parseUnsignedLong("FBD626CC4961A4FC", 16);
```

you can get the correct string representation with the function

```
String numberToPrint = Long.toUnsignedString(number);
```

If you now print `numberToPrint` you get

```
18146734407382312188
```

To be more exact, your number is still going to be a regular **signed** `long` which is why it shows overflow if printed directly. However, there are new static functions that will treat the value as if it was unsigned, such as this `Long.toUnsignedString(long x)` or `Long.compareUnsigned(long x, long y)`.

Answer (score 3):

The hexadecimal number `"FBD626CC4961A4FC"`, converted to decimal, is exactly `18146734407382312188`. That number is indeed larger than the maximum possible `long`, defined as [`Long.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#MAX_VALUE) and which is equal to 2<sup>63</sup>-1, or `9223372036854775807`:

```
System.out.println(new BigInteger("FBD626CC4961A4FC", 16)); // 18146734407382312188
System.out.println(Long.MAX_VALUE);                         // 9223372036854775807
```

As such, it's normal that you get back a negative number.

You do not have an exception, as it is exactly the purpose of those new `*Unsigned*` methods added in Java 8, to give the ability to handle unsigned longs (like [`compareUnsigned`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#compareUnsigned-long-long-) or [`divideUnsigned`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#divideUnsigned-long-long-)). Since the type `long` in Java [is still unsigned](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2), those methods work by understanding negative values as values greater than `MAX_VALUE`: it simulates an unsigned long. [`parseUnsignedLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseUnsignedLong-java.lang.String-int-) says:

> An unsigned integer maps the values usually associated with negative numbers to positive numbers larger than `MAX_VALUE`.

If you print a `long` that was the result of `parseUnsignedLong`, and it is negative, all it means is that the value is greater than the max long value as defined by the language, but that methods taking unsigned longs as parameter will correctly interpret those values, as if they were greater than the max value. As such, instead of printing it directly,  if you pass that number to [`toUnsignedString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toUnsignedString-long-int-), you'll get the right output, [like shown in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40637004/1743880). Not all of these methods are new to Java 8, for example [`toHexString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toHexString-long-) also interprets the given `long` as an unsigned long in base 16, and printing `Long.toHexString(Long.parseUnsignedLong("FBD626CC4961A4FC", 16))` will give you back the right hex String.

[`parseUnsignedLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseUnsignedLong-java.lang.String-int-) will throw an exception only when the value cannot be represented as an unsigned long, i.e. not a number at all, or greater than 2<sup>64</sup>-1 (and not 2<sup>63</sup>-1 which is the maximum value for a signed long).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it overflows when you are trying to print it, as it is converted to Java `long` type. To understand why let's take log2 of your dec value.

First thing, original value is `18146734407382312188`. It's log2 is ~63.9763437545.

Second, look into [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html): in java long type represents values of -2^63 and a maximum value of 2^63-1.

So, your value is obviously greater then 2^63-1, hence it overflows:

```
-2^63 + (18146734407382312188 - 2^63 + 1) = -300009666327239428
```

But as @Keiwan brilliantly mentioned, you still can print proper value using `Long.toUnsignedString(number);`

Answer (score 1):

Internally unsigned and signed numbers are represented in the same way, i.e. as 8 bytes in case of a long. The difference only how the "sign" bit interpreted, i.e. if you'd do the same in a C/C++ program and store your value into an `uint64_t` then cast/map it to a asigned `int64_t` you should get the same result.

Since the maximum value 8 bytes or 64 bits can hold is 2^64-1 that's the hard constraint for such numbers. Also Java doesn't directly support unsigned numbers and thus the only way to store an unsigned long in a `long` is to allow for a value that's higher than the signed `Long.MAX_VALUE`. In fact Java doesn't know whether the string/hexcode you're reading is meant to represent a signed or unsigned long so it's up to you to provide that interpretation, either by converting back to a string or using a larger datatype such as `BigInteger`.